# How can I find conflicting keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.4, using Safari 8.0.7.

When I press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Safari doesn't show all tabs, as it's supposed to be, but presents me with the crosshair you get when you would otherwise press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>.

When I press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, I also get the crosshair.
Pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> outside of Safari also gives me the crosshair.

I already checked all shortcuts defined under "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts" and I also used the apps *CheatSheet* and *KeyCue* to display shortcuts, but they only show <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> for "Show all tabs" in Safari and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> for taking selected screenshots.

How can I find out, where the conflicting key bind is coming from?

This behavior started a few days ago, but I can't seem to recall any specific changes or app installations, If there even were any...

Comment: just to correct you, the shift+7 key is actually "/" not the number 7.

Comment: it's actually \ not /  :)

Comment: I am using OS X with German language, so it's "7" because we have a different keyboard layout :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the culprit...

In order to find the error I tried several other numbers with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and found <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> triggering a screen recording interface I hadn't seen before.

Opening this interfaces options I found it originated from [CloudApp](https://www.getcloudapp.com) and there in CloudApps "Keyboard Shortcuts" I found it (see image).

[image: the interfering shortcut]

CloudApp must have integrated the shortcut with it's recent update.

I removed the shortcut and now Safari is working again as it should :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [ShortcutDetective](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) that shows you exactly which application binds the shortcuts. You can [watch the demo video](https://sayzlim.net/find-conflicting-shortucts-mac/) in my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The `ShortcutDetective` app, from [sayzlim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/55319/sayzlim) above, is the only and best solution I found, after hours of searching. It actually still works in `OS X Ventura`. BUT there were too many snags in finding the download link and getting the app to work so I will have to give the necessary details.

The `ShortcutDetective` [Download link](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/downloads/?file=ShortcutDetective.zip), which proved to be elusive and problematic, autodownloads to the default directory but you can click `here` and save to another directory:

[image]

When first opening the app, you get:

```
Accessibility Required
Please enable Accessibility and relaunch ShortcutDetective
Show Me How and Quit
```

[image]

Clicking the button goes to [Enable Accessibility on Mac OS X by Version](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/help/accessibility/versions.html) but the latest version listed is `macOS 10.15 Catalina`. (Ventura is macOS 10.13. Don't ask me why.) I tried to notify [sayzlim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/55319/sayzlim) but could find no way to do so.

In Ventura, you can do this by going to `System Settings->Privacy & Security->Accessibility` and enabling the app, which is disabled by default.

[image]

[image]

Open the app and press the shortcut that is giving conflicts and wait until it displays the apps that are using this shortcut:
[image]
In my case it was two different screen capture apps, so I removed the shortcut of one of them. Problem solved. Nice going `sayzlim`!

If anyone's got a better way, I'd like to see it.